# Can't insert correct "enable" secret password with Plink.exe for my Dell switch

Tags: switch, echo, plink

I'm trying to use "Plink.exe" to connect throught SSH to my Dell switch N1548P and run "enable" command to enter EXEC mode. I'm using Plink with CMD in Windows 10. This is the syntax:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>(
Again? echo enable
Again? echo pack3t2021!
Again? )|plink.exe -ssh dell@192.168.100.8 -pw Pack3t2021! -batch
Using username "dell".

console>enable
Password:************     #this are 12 characters#

Authentication failed.

console>
```

---

So, the second echo (`echo Pack3t2021!`) is the password for a total of 11 characters, while the characters after "Password:" of the switch are 12, there is an invisible character and for this reason the enable authentication fail. I don't know how to make it works, i tried everything.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with Powershell:

$plink = 'C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe'
$switch = "IP"
$username = "SSH-User"
$pw =   "SSH-Password"

(
Write-Output enable, Password for enable,
Write-Output config
) | plink -ssh $username@$switch -pw $pw